# Storing user input into dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

I would like to take user input and store it into a dataframe. User is to input make, model, type, and rating. Then I would like to print the dataframe table of the user inputs. So this is what I have so far

taking user input

```
t = int(input("Enter the number of car instances: "))
ca = cb = cc = cd = ce = cf = 0.0
carList = {'make': [],
           'model': [],
           'type': [],
           'rating': []}
df = pd.DataFrame(carList)

ca_sedan = ca_coupe = ca_suv = 0.0
cb_sedan = cb_coupe = cb_suv = 0.0
cc_sedan = cc_coupe = cc_suv = 0.0
cd_sedan = cd_coupe = cd_suv = 0.0
ce_sedan = ce_coupe = ce_suv = 0.0
cf_sedan = cf_coupe = cf_suv = 0.0

for _ in range(t):
    k = map(str, input("Enter the make,model,type,rating: ").split(','))
    if k[3] == 'A':
        ca += 1
        if k[2] == 'sedan': ca_sedan += 1
        if k[2] == 'coupe': ca_coupe += 1
        if k[2] == 'SUV': ca_suv += 1
    if k[3] == 'B':
        cb += 1
        if k[2] == 'sedan': cb_sedan += 1
        if k[2] == 'coupe': cb_coupe += 1
        if k[2] == 'SUV': cb_suv += 1
    if k[3] == 'C':
        cc += 1
        if k[2] == 'sedan': cc_sedan += 1
        if k[2] == 'coupe': cc_coupe += 1
        if k[2] == 'SUV': cc_suv += 1
    if k[3] == 'D':
        cd += 1
        if k[2] == 'sedan': cd_sedan += 1
        if k[2] == 'coupe': cd_coupe += 1
        if k[2] == 'SUV': cd_suv += 1
    if k[3] == 'E':
        ce += 1
        if k[2] == 'sedan': ce_sedan += 1
        if k[2] == 'coupe': ce_coupe += 1
        if k[2] == 'SUV': ce_suv += 1
    if k[3] == 'F':
        cf += 1
        if k[2] == 'sedan': cf_sedan += 1
        if k[2] == 'coupe': cf_coupe += 1
        if k[2] == 'SUV': cf_suv += 1
    carList.append(Car(k[0], k[1], k[2], k[3]))
```

Comment: When I run the program i'm getting this message "if k[3] == 'A': TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: You should edit your question with any extra data, rather than add it in comments. It’s easier to see!

Comment: Anyway, try replacing `k = map(...)` with `k = list(map(...))`

Comment: If you're okay with using jupyter notebook I can recommend [qgrid](https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid)